# How to measure time executed by a method called by a Junit 4 Test Case using Spring AOP or any other method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, aop

I have a requirement to measure method execution time bye each methods in a JUnit 4 test framework. 
Consider this test :

```
package org.test.libtest

import org.some.lib.Class
..
public class  testMyApp{
    @Test
    public void testSomething(){
        //Asume following method returns a Long value after doing a complex calc
        int a=100, b=100;
        Long ac=org.some.lib.Class.doSomething(int a, int b);
        Assert.assertEquals(100,ac);
    }   
    ..
    ..

}
```

Requirement is to measure the time executed by method `org.some.lib.Class.doSomething(..)` .

We can get time executed by Test Method testMyApp using Spring AOP and Junit's own @Rule, Stopwatch classes. 
But how can we measure the the time executed by the underlying method call by a test method?

Comment: Something like the `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor` will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure your method's execution time with the following code

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// here is your method you want to measure
long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

If you want more precise measurements of time you can use `System.nanoTime();` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: See, I am using AOP to avoid adding these statements for each of @Test annotated methods.  Appropriate solution would be, a logger which would get the execution times as and when test method is executed. Point is I dont want to modify the existing test code.